# All elements of this array are the same, but why?

Tags: php, arrays

I have some code which loops through an array, as well as an array within that array, and creates a list of all items. The outputted list will be used to make a menu.

The data, before it is added to `$new_items`, echo's as:

```
Lane
Financial Literacy
IDA Required
```

However, at the end of the foreach, if I dump `$new_items` I expected it to be the same. But it wasn't:

```
IDA Required
IDA Required
IDA Required
```

It seems the `$new_items` array is adding each item, but the values are being overridden with the last element to get added.

The variables appear correct before they are added to `$new_items` But **where do they change?**

### Here is my code:

```
$new_items = array();

foreach($classes as $loc) {
  // Clone the original item, change the given values so they suit our class
  $loc_item = $menu_items[$key];

  $loc_item->ID = new_class_menu_id();
  $loc_item->url = site_url( sprintf('/?post_type=product&class-location=%s', urlencode($loc['term']->slug)) );
  $loc_item->title = $loc['term']->name . ' <span class="class-count">'. $loc['class_count'] .'</span>';
  // $loc_item->menu_item_parent // Keep the original menu parent for locations.

  echo "Location Name: {$loc_item->title}\n"; // #### DEBUG #####
  $new_items[] = $loc_item;

  foreach($loc['categories'] as $cat) {
    $cat_item = $menu_items[$key];

    $cat_item->ID = new_class_menu_id();
    $cat_item->url = site_url( sprintf('/?post_type=product&class-location=%s&product_cat=%s', urlencode($loc['term']->slug), urlencode($cat['term']->slug)) );
    $cat_item->title = $cat['term']->name . ' <span class="class-count">'. $cat['class_count'] .'</span>';
    $cat_item->menu_item_parent = $loc_item->ID; // Categories should be nested under their location

    echo "Category Name: {$cat_item->title}\n"; // #### DEBUG #####
    $new_items[] = $cat_item;
  }

  echo "New_Items: \n"; // #### DEBUG #####
  foreach($new_items as $i => $item) echo "Item {$i}: {$item->title}\n"; // #### DEBUG #####
  echo "\n\n\n"; // #### DEBUG #####
}
function new_class_menu_id() {
  static $i = 1000;
  $i++;
  return $i;
}
```

### Debug Output:

```
Location Name: Lane <span class="class-count">1</span>
Category Name: Financial Literacy <span class="class-count">1</span>
Category Name: IDA Required <span class="class-count">1</span>
New_Items: 
Item 0: IDA Required <span class="class-count">1</span>
Item 1: IDA Required <span class="class-count">1</span>
Item 2: IDA Required <span class="class-count">1</span>
```

### Expected Output:

```
Item 0: Lane <span class="class-count">1</span>
Item 1: Financial Literacy <span class="class-count">1</span>
Item 2: IDA Required <span class="class-count">1</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not cloning your object, you are passing the reference and overwriting the class members. For example, if you try this code:

```
<?
class SomeClass {
 public $ID;
 public $url;
 public $title;

 function __construct() {
  $this->ID = 1;
  $this->url = "www.stackoverflow.com";
  $this->title = "MyTitle";
 }
}

$key=0;
$menu_items[$key] = new SomeClass();

// As the object has been constructed, the ID=1
var_dump($menu_items[$key]);

$loc_item = $menu_items[$key];
$loc_item->ID = 2;

// changed in loc_item var, that refers to the same instance
var_dump($menu_items[$key]);

?>
```

You will see that $menu_items[$key] has ID=1 in the first var_dump, and ID=2 after it is changed in $loc_item.

If you want to follow this approach, maybe you should implement the clone method as it is described here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Comment: This makes sense. I may have done the same thing in PHP 4 which apparently did make a copy by default. Not sure though. Anyway, simply sticking the `clone` keyword before the object fixed everything! Genius! Thank you! My usage: `$loc_item = clone $menu_items[$key];`

Answer (score 1):

Answer is very simple - because You have only working on one object ($menu_items[$key])

look my example to understand:

```
 $items = array();
 $object = new stdClass();

 $object->title = 'test1';

 $items[] = $object;
 var_dump($items);  // title is 'test1'

 $object->title = 'test2';
 var_dump($items); // now title is 'test2'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense now. I wasn't aware objects are passed by reference. Although I'm giving the answer to @lpg since he provided the solution as well (the `clone` keyword).