# Why do all of the elements in this array have the same value?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a program designed to convert weight on Earth into mass into weight on other planets.  `userWeight()`, `fileToken()`, and `printTable()` are methods that are defined elsewhere in the program.

```
double earthWeight = userWeight();

// initialize arrays
String[] planet = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};

double[] gravity = new double[planet.length];
for(int index = 0; index < gravity.length; index++) {
    gravity[index] = Double.parseDouble(fileToken(index));
}

double[] mass = new double[planet.length];
for(int index = 0; index < mass.length; index++) {
    mass[index] = earthWeight * 453.59237 / (gravity[index] / gravity[2]);
}

double[] weight = new double[planet.length];
for(int index = 0; index < mass.length; index++) {
    weight[index] = mass[index] * (gravity[index] / gravity[2]) / 453.59237;
}

// print table
printTable(planet, gravity, weight);
```

All of the elements in `weight` have exactly the same value as `earthWeight`.  They aren't supposed to be.

I think there is something wrong with this line:

```
weight[index] = mass[index] * (gravity[index] / gravity[2]) / 453.59273;
```

but I'm not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

**Note:** This is not a duplicate of [All elements of this array are the same, but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089646/all-elements-of-this-array-are-the-same-but-why)  That person was writing in php, I am writing in Java.  My question is specific to *this* program.

Comment: What is the type of weight ?

Comment: I don't know what fileToken is, but are you sure that it's returning correct, different values for each planet (index)?

Comment: @SauloAires weight is in pounds, and mass is grams

Comment: Can you check if the gravity and mass array have the correct values ?

Comment: I suggest you to print every array with `Arrays.toString(array)` after each for.

Comment: Looks like the third formula is just the opposite of the second formula. Means you are dividing by what you multiplied and multiplying by what you divided. So you get back your earth weight.

Comment: @SauloAires gravity takes data from a text file, all of those values are correct.  I checked mass using a print statement, all of those values are correct.  The only array that has incorrect values is weight.

Comment: @RealSkeptic is right, check `earthWeight * 453.59237 / (gravity[index] / gravity[2]) * (gravity[index] / gravity[2]) / 453.59273`, it yields `earthWeight` .

Comment: put some parenthesis, like : mass[index] * ((gravity[index] / gravity[2]) / 453.59237), just to be more clear

Comment: Furthermore, if I remember my physics right, the mass should be equal anywhere (unless you're traveling at a very high velocity), it's only the gravity and weight that change.

Comment: What do you see when you step through the code in your debugger?

Comment: http://spacegid.com/media/ves/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191/realskeptic) mentioned in comment, that you have a reversed formula. If you will pass the `mass[index]` formula instead of the result value, you will see that nothing exists anymore except for the weight of Earth. :)

[image: ![Formulas]

Comment: I took the liberty of replacing your handwritten image with an actual formula (using MathJax on an SE where this is possible). Feel free to roll back if you think I accidentally removed something.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen no, no :) Looks much better, I just had pen and notepad to check it quickly :)